# saving file as current logged in user

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way i can create my file as the current logged in user %username% in C.

For example:

```
char oBuffer[MAX_PATH];
memset(oBuffer, 0, MAX_PATH);
ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\\", oBuffer, MAX_PATH);
CreateDirectoryA(oBuffer, 0);
strcat(oBuffer, "%username%.txt");
strcpy(LOG_PATH, oBuffer);
logfile = fopen(LOG_PATH, "a+");
```

The below statement would work in the way:

```
strcat(oBuffer, "file.txt");
```

Comment: you'd call `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` on the `%username%.txt` too

Comment: I tried that but failed to reference ```ExpandEnvironmentStrings ``` as a variable. Kindly elaborate on how i could apply it correctly.

Comment: In the same way as you already do it with the directory!

Comment: Please include your failed try and info in what way it failed (error, etc.), then it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: How about expanding the `%username%.txt` to the end of the string already in `oBuffer` using `size_t len = strlen(oBuffer);` `ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%.txt", &oBuffer[len], MAX_PATH - len);`? By the way, for consistency, you should probably be using `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA`,

Comment: @IanAbbott I think that's what i was looking for. The 1st comment directed me to the right path however I had not yet understood how to practically apply it. Thanks alot all